# Custom cursor to entire page

Tags: html, css, cursor

I have css cursor for my website. But it seem only take effect on div inside body tag.

My **body css**

```
body{
   background: #00a2ff url('../img/bg.png');
   overflow:hidden;
   cursor: not-allowed;
}
```

and **index.html**

```
<body>
<div class="content">
    <div class="logo"></div>
    <div class="wave1"></div>
    <div class="wave2"></div>
</div>
</body>
```

Display

https://i.stack.imgur.com/XlGuK.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/yTWhe.png

Sorry for my bad English.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify an explicit height for `<body>` so that it can fill the entire of the page.

For instance:

```css
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0; margin: 0; /* reset the default stylesheet */
}
```

**Note:** Since a percentage value of [`height`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/height) is relative to the height of the parent, you should specify a `height` on `<html>` element as well.

**[EXAMPLE HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/hashem/3mwkLh8s/)**

Answer (score 0):

use masking-div

you can set the cursor to not-allowedon the div and don't have to worry about links as they are "under" your masking div. Here's some example CSS for the "masking div":

```
body { height: 100%; }
div#mask { cursor: not-allowed; z-index: 999; height: 100%; width: 100%; }
```